# Checker Shader Node - strange distortion Blender 2.92.0

Tags: shader-nodes

I've been working on a long-term project and am in the process of unwrapping the objects.

One of the materials I'm using is created from Checker Shader Node. I tend to use this during unwrapping to help me determine if any major distortion is appearing during the unwrap process.

I've noticed recently that the Checker node seems to be distorting the check pattern on pipe objects. what's weird though is the distortion seems to be happening on any new objects I am unwrapping, older pipe object using the same material seem to be ok (using an earlier version of blender)

In comparison I also used a UV Grid BitMap Image . which does apply well to the pipe I have linked an example of the problem in pdf format and supplied an example .blend file

[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iXF1xu5QfLYeyFJDWpkGEXw6O1TUcZS0

Comment: Hello :). You probably noticed, but your checker texture isn't connected to UV coordinates. So it's using generated coordinates by default :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as Jachym correctly said, just plugin the texture coordinate node, UV to vector and play with scale and you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you all.  Your are absolutely correct, I must of accidentally deleted that node.  Its working as expected now